# call network periodically for any updates only in foreground

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, freeze, periodic-task

I would like to periodically check for updates doing network call every 30 sec and update listview accordingly, only if my screen is in foreground (thus not from service). What I am doing for that is -

```
private void refreshPeriodically()
{
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {       
                    try {


                        new callToMyAsyncTask().execute(context); 

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 30*1000); //execute in every 30 sec
}
```

but, that hangs my list while scrolling.

What should I do for that?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use handler. When you call `handler.post()` it will run on `UI` thread so your list will freeze. Start a new `callToMyAsyncTask` in run method in `TimerTask` without using handler and you can call `timer.cancel()` when your activity is not in foreground.

Also I think you should use `scheduleAtFixedRate` instead of `schedule`.

However I think you may have some problems without service. When you cancel timer it will not cancel current `callToMyAsyncTask` and when it call `onPostExecute` activity is no longer available. But I don't know it will crash or not.